# How to calculate the radius of a circle composed of many smaller circles?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I'm making a CAD model of a ball bearing.
It contains 14 balls (perfect spheres) arranged in a perfect circle pattern.

So if each ball has a radius of $r$, how do I calculate the radius of the entire circular pattern?
(I'm looking for the radius of the circle containing the CENTER POINTS of all the balls.)

This example photo is a ball bearing with 9 balls, but mine has 14 balls - but this should help illustrate the situation:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine a line drawn from the center of each sphere to that of the next. That will product a $14$-sided regular polygon with side length $2r$. Its [circumradius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#Circumradius) will be of length
$$R=\frac{r}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{14}\right)},$$
from which we conclude that the radius of the outer circle will be of length
$$r+R=r\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{14}\right)}\right).$$

(I'm not quite sure which of these two measurements you are interested in, so I provided both...)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I edited the question to specify the circle containing all the center points, which I think is your first equation (hence why the outer circle would contain one extra $r$).

Comment: @Giffyguy Indeed it is, glad this helps!